# Xaomi Redmi 3s debbuging Xamarin apps

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, usb

I develop Xamarin.Android apps and I use Xaomi Redmi 3s to debuging mode.

Everything works fine , but I always receives 2 irritating questions about 
acept installation via usb ( Mono Shared Runtime , Xamarin Android Support )

I choose checkbox 'save installation' but it's not work .

Is it possible to disable the options for protection against installation of the application or whether it is these applications permanently set ?

Comment: Do you have  `Enable "Unknown Sources"` set on your device?

Comment: "Unknow Sources I set ... i found another option... "